# LibGDX - Get width of label cell in ImageTextButton

Tags: libgdx

I have ImageTextButtons within a container Table. I would like to dynamically change the width of this table and have the ImageTextButtons respond in a particular manner. What I would like them to do is fade in the label text depending on the percentage of the text shown.

I believe I am dynamically setting the table width and contents correctly. As per the LibGDX documents we should not explicitly set the widgets dimensions, but the table (container) cell dimensions. So for testing, I have a simple clickListener on what of the buttons like this;

```
    button.addListener(new ClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
            super.clicked(event, x, y);
            float max = container.getCell(button).getMaxWidth();
            container.getCell(button).width(max*0.9f);
            container.invalidate();
        }
    });
```

This works fine, I click it and the cell (and the widget) shrink 90% each time.

For the next step, I thought it would be as simple as this, in my custom ImageTextButton's draw() method;

```
    glyphWidth = getLabel().getGlyphLayout().width;
    labelCellWidth = getLabelCell().getMinWidth(); ///<--problem here

    float glyphOpacityMultiplier = MathUtils.clamp(labelCellWidth/glyphWidth, 0f, 1f);

    origLabelColor = getLabel().getColor().cpy();
    newLabelColor = origLabelColor.cpy();
    newLabelColor = new Color(newLabelColor.r, newLabelColor.g, newLabelColor.b, newLabelColor.a*glyphOpacityMultiplier);

    getLabel().setColor(newLabelColor);
    super.draw(batch, parentAlpha);
    getLabel().setColor(origLabelColor);
```

This all works, except for the fact I can't find any method to give me with actual width of the Cell that contains the label. Since the ImageTextButton itself is also a Table, I tried to do button.invalidate() in the ClickListener too but it didn't help. These are the methods I have tried so far;

```
    getLabelCell().getMinWidth();
    getLabelCell().getMaxWidth();
    getLabelCell().getPrefWidth();
    getLabelCell().getActorWidth();
    getLabelCell().getSpaceLeft();
    getLabelCell().getSpaceRight();
```

None of them seem to update and give me the correct size, however I know something is working somewhere because I turned on "setClip(true)" on the ImageTextButton, and the label text is successfully being clipped within the boundaries of the NinePatch background when it is resized. So how do I get the correct size?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Oops.. solved it. I thought the cell containing the label would be offset and sized by the NinePatch background but its not, it is full size but has padding. Therefore the answer is;

```
    labelCellWidth = getWidth()-getPadLeft()-getPadRight();
```